# How do you see the full name of a track in Google Music?

Tags: google-play-music

For podcasts with a long name, it sucks not to be able to see the full name of the track. How do you see the full name of a track in Google Music?

Comment: What version of Google Play Music (GPM)? Mine used to display the entire Podcast path, which was a problem, but currently shields the path and displays only the filename, generally just an mp3. This is current to a Galaxy S3 with GPM 4.4.811H526848. That version may even be out of date, since I generally use ES File Explorer to play media files and have not updated GPM in some time.

Comment: It's v5.2.1204L.814012 (gee, Google really put an effort into sucking at the versioning of this). Anyway, maybe that's why you don't GPM, it used to suck, now it's pretty good and the most beautiful player I'm aware of. The problem is just that the tracks with long titles such as in podcasts are a problem to read, especially because the name usually starts with "podcast #xx (name of program)"